# Create separate dataframes by iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like so:

```
Year  Month  Day
1984  01     01
1984  02     01
1985  01     01
1985  02     01
1986  01     01
1986  02     01
```

and I want to create seperate dataframe based on year and month.  So every `Year == 1984` and `Month == 01` gets its own dataframe. And every `Year == 1985` and `month == 01` gets its own dataframe So for every possible combination of years and months I want a new dataframe.  This is a simplified example as my years go from 1984 to 2011 with every month.  I know I could use `.isin` to do this manually but I would like to automate it if possible.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension.

```
dfs = {year: {month: pd.DataFrame() for month in range(1, 13)} 
       for year in df.Year.unique()}
```

This returns a nested dictionary keyed off of year and month with an empty dataframe inside (you didn't specify what you wanted the dataframe to contain...)